# Mysql Connect to external/remote server outside the VLAN

Tags: php, mysql, linux, vpn

I am trying to connect to an external mysql server from a computer which is inside a vlan where my application will run. The remote server is not a member of the vlan. The following is what I have tried so far.

**Mysql Port forwarding from my vlan server**

```
ssh -L 3306:my-vlan-server-ip:3306 user-at-external-server@external-server-ip
```

In this case I get a ssh timeout message. 
Tried to do it directly from my php mysql_connect I get mysql error #111 yet I have already edited the **my.cnf** as:

```
#skip-networking
bind-address  =my-vlan-server-ip
```

**My php db connect script**

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("external-server-ip","user","pass");
if($conn)
{
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "fail";
}
?>
```

Kindly someone help.Let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are running the ssh client on the vlan server (=my-vlan-server-ip)?

The local tunnelling (-L) basicly forwards the first port to the given port on the given address, i.e -L 80:someserver:8080 forwards port 80 on the local machine to port 8080 on someserver...  so if you want to connect to 3306 on the remote server via ssh you do:

ssh -L 3306:external-server-ip:3306 user-at-external-server@external-server-ip
(or just -L 3306:localhost:3306, localhost will then refer to the server to which you are connecting, ie external-server-ip)

localhost:3306 is then forwarded to external-server-ip:3306

in the php script running on my-vlan-server-ip you then connect to localhost:3306, which is then forwarded to external-server-ip by ssh...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. My-vlan-server has ssh and runs in a cloud while the other server is a shared host with a cpanel.(It has the database I am trying to connect to). I have tried your suggestion and what I am get is a timeout message.i.e for ssh -L 3306:external-server-ip:3306 user-at-external-server@external-server-ip, this is what I get, ssh: connect to host external-server-p port 22: Connection timed out. What could be the reason/error for the timeout?

Comment: hmm...  the external server is running an ssh server? do you have shell access (you can log on via ssh?)

Comment: No ssh at all.I access it from the cpanel only

Comment: then it can't be done... ssh tunneling requires that you are able to log on to the server with ssh (you have so-called "shell-access"), something most web providers don't give you... I use webfaction, they allow for ssh...  so, I'm sorry, but ssh tunneling won't work if the remote server doesn't allow you to log in by ssh... might make a "bridging" php page that accepts a query and returns the results as a JSON page that you can easily parse into objects in PHP, but I fear that will be somewhat slow...

Comment: to explain a little further: basically ssh tunneling works like this: say you use -L 80:localhost:8080 your ssh client opens a listening port on your local computer as specified (80), any data coming via this port is sent via ssh to the ssh server you are connected to, the ssh server will then connect to the port (8080) on the server you specified and the connection finds it's intended target...

Comment: You are right. I tried it from another host which offers the ssh support and it works fine.Thanks a lot. You have made me understand how port forwarding works better.Thanks alot, you saved me a lot of stress. I have been working on it for 4 days.You are great!

Comment: my pleasure... have been using that feature a lot with my own VPS, works like a charm... excellent for connecting to Webmin or a database server hidden behind the firewall...

Comment: I think this is an area I should try and explore for more knowledge.Any tutorial or even a blog you can recommend?

Comment: there are a number of pages detailing ssh syntax (or putty on windows)... just ask the great oracle in the sky a.k.a. Google